# Get coordinates from location_once_scrolled_into_view result

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I'm developing the usual script to test feature of my new passion and that's the result:

Script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.it')
driver.maximize_window()

try:
time.sleep(5)
insert = driver.find_element_by_id('gbqfq')
insertloc = insert.location_once_scrolled_into_view
print insertloc
finally:
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
{u'y': 316, u'x': 364}
```

I need to add to my script something like:
x = insertloc.x and y = insertloc. y that gives the relative coordinates

I've try it but this is the result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\python\selenium\webdriver\googlelocation.py", line 21, in <m
odule>
print insertloc.x
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'x'
```

I have look around for a solution and I have surely found one, with miles of code to write, working on the string. But I'm sure that something more clean exist so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transform dict in a list and get result.

```
xy = insertloc.values()
print xy
y = xy[0]
x = xy[1]
print y
print x
```

Output:

```
[316, 364]
316
364
```

Now you can use the coordinates if you need.